# Drupal 7 FAPI ajax and jquery submit event

Tags: drupal, jquery, drupal-7

I am using #ajax in submit button of a form created using FAPI. Now when user submits the form, I want to run some jQuery validation before the form is submitted through ajax. As #ajax prevents events related to submit button such as submit, click, mousedown, keypress etc. I am not able to catch submit event using jQuery.

For now as a workaround, I have added custom code in ajax.js (misc/ajax.js) :

```
Drupal.ajax = function (base, element, element_settings) {
    ...
    beforeSubmit: function (form_values, element_settings, options) {
        //my custom code
        alert(1);
        ...
```

This is against drupal best practices as I am hacking the core. Please any one can help me to do the same from my custom js file or any other approach to validate the content before ajax submit.

Answer (score 2):

I think the accepted answer on the following post answers your question: [How to extend or "hook" Drupal Form AJAX?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9920/how-to-extend-or-hook-drupal-form-ajax)

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.MyModule = {
attach: function (context, settings) {

    // Overwrite beforeSubmit
    Drupal.ajax['some_element'].options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {
        // ... Some staff added to form_values
    }
    //Or you can overwrite beforeSubmit
    Drupal.ajax['some_element'].options.beforeSerialize = function (element, options) {

        // ... Some staff added to options.data
        // Also call parent function
        Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSerialize(element, options);
    }

                //...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried----       Drupal.ajax['some_element'].options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element_settings, options) {
    alert(1);
    } -----
and also -----
Drupal.ajax.options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element_settings, options) {
    alert(1);
    } -----
With no luck. Am i missing anything, and what arguments do I need to pass to ajax['some_element'] i.e some_element is the argument passed to Drupal.ajax function

Comment: same problem here i dnt know some stuff  in below link. as i do not get any solution to work. Drupal.ajax['some_element'].options.beforeSubmit

Comment: are you sure you have not this part of code inside $(document).ready event listener? Look at https://drupal.org/node/304258#drupal-behaviors, when Drupal attaches properties to behavior.

Answer (score 0):

i put this in the attach function

```
for (var base in settings.ajax) {
  Drupal.ajax[base].options.beforeSubmit = function(form_values, element, options){
    console.log('call your func');
  }
}
```

it works!